# get vars Twig Template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this Include

main.html.twig

```
{% set vars ={'id': user.id,'order': 'true'} %}
{% include "BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig" with vars %}
```

OrderForm.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('myaction',{'id': post.id,'order':order})}) }}
```

Can I change the `id` and `order` in `OrderForm.html.twig` with

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('myaction',vars)}) }}
```

Comment: Have you tried it ? Do you get any error ? I'm not sure you can just use `vars` like you did, you're probably gonna have to do `{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('myaction', {'id': vars.id, 'order': vars.order})}) }}`

Comment: @paulgv yes, i tried with vars and I got an error

Comment: What's the error ? Did you try what I suggested in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
{% include "BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig" with {'vars': vars} %}
```

when you do

```
{% include "BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig" with vars %}
```

its the same as

```
{% include "BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig" with {'id': user.id,'order': 'true'} %}
```

so what is really passed to the `BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig` is an array, not 'vars' variable

Comment: `{% include "BDMOrderBundle::OrderForm.html.twig" with {'vars': vars} %}` Works ! thanks